# python infinite loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, while-loop

I am making a game in python and I have encountered a problem where an infinite has been created. I'm new to programming and I'm not sure how to fix it. Any help would be amazing.

```
money = 100
opp = dealer()
me = player()

while money > 0:
if me > opp:
    money = money * 1.5
    print "Winner, winner, chicken dinner! You have $%d!" % money
elif opp > me:
    money = money * 0.75
    print "Dealer wins with %d. You have $%d reamaining." % (opp, money)
elif me == 21:
    money = money * 1.5
    print "Blackjack! You have $%d!" % money
```

The code is doing exactly what I've asked from it (which is to print the line). How can I make it print the line once and then just restart and deal new cards.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Move the code that reads the `dealer` and the `player` hands to the beginning of loop:

```
while money > 0:
  opp = dealer()
  me = player()
  if me > opp:
    money = money * 1.5
    print "Winner, winner, chicken dinner! You have $%d!" % money
  elif opp > me:
    money = money * 0.75
    print "Dealer wins with %d. You have $%d reamaining." % (opp, money)
  elif me == 21:
    money = money * 1.5
    print "Blackjack! You have $%d!" % money
```

Comment: @iamtesla: You're welcome. Also consider changing the `while money > 0` condition, because with your current code, `money` will always be greater than zero, since multiplying it by 0.75 will not make its value go to zero. That is, you still allow a player to play when his money is 0.000000000001.

Comment: I quickly realized that! I changed it to plus or minus 10 instead. Thanks for looking out.